# Adding Tabs menu containing objects

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

I am creating a custom object but I need to add a tab menu inside. Is it at least possible ?
I have my fields and my sections on the page but I neet to be able to view the objects details.

Here is an example from FileMaker :
[image: tabs]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lightning experience then it is possible in standard way. For classic it is not possible in standard way yo need development please clarify.

Comment: So I need to use Lightning ?